# If a closed set E is nowhere dense, must each of its points be isolated?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would think not. E closed means E is its own closure. Nowhere dense means the interior of the closure and therefore of E is empty. To me this means that every neighborhood of every point in E contains a point in R\E. An isolated point must have a neighborhood in which it is the only point of E. Again, I don't find an implication. Is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: The simplest counterexample is perhaps an increasing convergent sequence and its limit.

Comment: Thanks, this example is excellent in its simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cantor sets or Fat cantor sets work as counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seriously studied the fascinating Cantor sets yet, so I'll have to lean on sequences like $\(1/n$\) and it's limit point 0. I am thinking the point 0 is the only point that is not isolated in the closure of $\({1/n}\)$, but that this one point is enough for the set not to be isolated.

Comment: @senselessapprentice It turns out that these cases like sequences and sets like it, e.g. we can add a sequences, each converging to another $\frac{1}{n}$, to get a countable subset that is closed nowhere dense and is has countably many non-isolated points as well, are special, and called "scattered sets". And every closed set (in $\mathbb{R}$,e.g.) can be written as the union of a perfect set and a scattered set in a unique way. The perfect ones are like the Cantor set. So these are the basic types.

Answer (score 2):

You complicate too much. The x-axis in R2 is a closed nowhere dense set without isolate point...